# Custom post using elementor not displaying correctly

Tags: custom-post-types

Sitting with a weird one, I'm currently busy rebuilding a site on Elementor. The site uses custom post types, I copied over CPT code to the functions file, created the archive template, and assigned it to the CPT, but the archive template does not show up, just a single post. This the link to the CPT: https://dev.inthebunch.co.za/live-streaming/

below is the cpt code I have in the functions file.

```
//** Live streams **//
```

function cptui_register_my_cpts_livestreams() {

```
/**
 * Post Type: live streams.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Live stream', '' ),
    "menu_name" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "all_items" => __( 'All live streams', '' ),
    "add_new" => __( 'Add new live stream', '' ),
    "add_new_item" => __( 'Add new live stream', '' ),
    "edit_item" => __( 'Edit live stream', '' ),
    "view_item" => __( 'New live stream', '' ),
    "view_items" => __( 'View live streams', '' ),
    "search_items" => __( 'Search live streams', '' ),
    "archives" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Live streams', '' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => "live-streaming",
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "live-stream", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "thumbnail", "genesis-cpt-archives-settings", 'genesis-seo' ),
    'yarpp_support' => true,
);

register_post_type( "livestreams", $args );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_livestreams' );

Comment: Do you happen to have a post or page also named live-streaming?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I just figured it out. It seems that you have to have the single post template set up as well and not just the archive template.